# How specify own toolbar in CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have installed a default toolbar. Now want to add some tollbar buttons.
Here tells how add:
http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html

I added code from example to file `config.js` at:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
   //HERE
};
```

But it does not work

Comment: Well, we don't see the code you pasted "HERE", we don't know what happened, we don't know whether you cleared browser cache, whether error is being thrown. We know nothing. Please edit your question.